# How to access an object with array in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Here's my code 
slot.interment.strInteITypeID.prices

The output is

```
[
  { 
    "strPriceID": 1, 
    "decPriceAmount": "15000.00", 
    "created_at": "2017-08-19 02:28:04",
    "updated_at": "2017-08-19 02:28:04" 
  }
]
```

How to access decPriceAmount???

Comment: `slot.interment.strInteITypeID.prices[0].decPriceAmount`

Comment: `nameOfArray[0]["decPriceAmount"]`?

Answer (score 3):

You have an array. You need to access the current item via index (`[0]`-the first item, because you have only one item there) and then access property of that object via `.` dot syntax or `[]` syntax.

```js
const data = [ 
{ 
   "strPriceID": 1, 
   "decPriceAmount": "15000.00", 
   "created_at": "2017-08-19 02:28:04",
   "updated_at": "2017-08-19 02:28:04" 
}];

console.log(data[0].decPriceAmount);
```